# How to check busy call forwarding is enabled/disabled?

Tags: android

I use [PhoneStateListener#onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(boolean)) method to listen the busy call forwarding enable/disable, but onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged method always give false.

Note: I enable/disable the all call forwarding, onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged method is working.

How can I check the busy call forwarding enable/disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you cant. There is no API to check the callforwarding in Android.